# Can't connect to ADB control socket:Connection refused

Tags: android, android-logcat

I am not getting the proper logcat in android studio,
Device i am using is : XOLO Q800

when ever i connect it to my PC, I get the following logcat :

```
03-02 16:53:21.345 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO)
03-02 16:53:21.345 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc E/jdwp: jdwp::setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)
03-02 16:53:21.346 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: Can't connect to ADB control socket:Connection refused
03-02 16:53:37.427 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: trying to receive file descriptor from ADB
03-02 16:53:38.111 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: received file descriptor 49 from ADB
03-02 16:53:38.115 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.118 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.118 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000C7D7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
03-02 16:53:38.119 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.119 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x17, id=0x4000C7D8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0xC
03-02 16:53:38.121 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.121 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000C7D9, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
03-02 16:53:38.123 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.123 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x13, id=0x4000C7DA, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x8
03-02 16:53:38.123 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.123 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7DB, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:38.172 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.172 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:38.173 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.173 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:38.174 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.174 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:38.673 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:38.673 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:38.673 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:39.175 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:39.175 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:39.176 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:39.679 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:39.679 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E6, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:39.685 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:40.179 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:40.179 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:40.179 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:40.680 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:40.680 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7E8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:40.681 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:41.182 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:41.182 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7EE, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:41.182 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:41.682 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:41.683 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7F4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:41.683 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
03-02 16:53:42.183 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: processIncoming
03-02 16:53:42.183 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x4000C7F5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
03-02 16:53:42.184 12668-12674/com.app.hdfc D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
```

and this is continuous. I even add a filter to the logcat but i dont get any logcat. how can i solve this issue?

Comment: it seems your device is blocking connections in the adb port, your device may have separate developer options that you need to enable in order open this port

Comment: but why do i get handle packet and process incoming log continuously? @Bhargav